# having SSO within some Laravel applications

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, single-sign-on

I have two or three PHP websites done by Laravel and a forum which is implemented in NodeJs. How could I build an SSO between them so that when a user signs in to one of them he will be authenticated in the others as well?

Comment: this might help : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

Comment: Well you can always use a custom session stored in a shared database table.